# How to set Custom overlay view on Editing View of UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

All

I have create UIImagePickerController with delegate and picking images from PhotoLibrary.

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

And when application reach to Editing view of UIImagePickerController i set one Overlay view and create two buttons for it. 
**`Cancel and Choose`**

On Cancel Button click

```
[imagePicker popToViewController:[currentViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

this cod work fine..

But `choose` Button does not working, 
if i set code like here,

```
[self imagePickerController:imagePicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:[imagePicker mediaTypes]];
```

than it returns NULL value of info dictionary.

Is that any other way to set overlay view on Editing ImagePicker ?

Regards,

Comment: Can u let us know the function of choose button?

Comment: Choose button work exact same as in Editing UIImagePickerViewController of choose button.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
CustomOverlayView *CustomOverlayView = [[CustomOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;     
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
        imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
        [imagePickerController.view addSubview:CustomOverlayView];
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];

    }
```

Comment: use this  imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

Comment: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{} this is delgete

Comment: check this[imagePicker mediaTypes]